# The random.randint import doesn't seem to be working correctly

Tags: python

This is my first question on Stack and I am really hoping someone else has had this same problem and can help me.

I have written the below code using Python 3.7.6 that randomly picks a card suit and a corresponding value based on a dict I have built. This code was working absolutely fine yesterday and the day before, however, today the random_number variable only seems to select 0 for the value_2 variable. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks:

```
import random
keys = list(deck.keys())

def random_card_generator():
    random_number = random.randint(0,8)
    random_word = random.choice(keys)

    if random_word.find('Ace') != -1:
        choose = 0
        print(random_word)
        while choose != 1 or choose != 11:
            choose = int(input('Would you like 1 or 11?: '))
            if choose == 1 or choose == 11:
                return choose, random_word
                break
            else:
                print('That is not a valid number. Please choose either 1 or 11')
                choose
    elif random_word.find('King') or random_word.find('Jack') or random_word.find('Queen') != -1:
        value = deck[random_word][0], random_word
        return value
    else:
        value_1 = deck[random_word][random_number], random_word
        return value_1
```

Comment: There is no `value_2` variable. Can you show `deck`?

Comment: Have you checked the value of `random_number` each time or are you just looking at the final card choice?

Comment: Can you clarify how you have checked that ``random_number`` is 0? Are you sure you are not in the ``elif`` clause, in which the index ``0`` is always used?

Comment: apologies @JanChristophTerasa i meant value_1. Please see deck that I have subsequently posted

Comment: @MisterMiyagi please see my deck dict structure below. I have now changed the elif clause to != -1 for all the .find() conditions and it seems to work again. It is really strange as I only had the singe != -1 yesterday and the code still executed as necessary. Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be certain without seeing how your `deck` is structured, but I  think the error is in this line:

```
elif random_word.find('King') or random_word.find('Jack') or random_word.find('Queen') != -1:
```

This needs to be

```
elif random_word.find('King') != -1 or random_word.find('Jack') != -1 or random_word.find('Queen') != -1:
```

Comment: deck = {'Spades':[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'King of Spades':[10], 'Queen of Spades':[10], 'Jack of Spades':[10], 'Ace of Spades':[1,11], 
'Diamonds':[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'King of Diamonds':[10], 'Queen of Diamonds':[10], 'Jack of Diamonds':[10], 'Ace of Diamonds':[1,11], 
'Hearts':[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'King of Hearts':[10], 'Queen of Hearts':[10], 'Jack of Hearts':[10], 'Ace of Hearts':[1,11], 
'Clubs':[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'King of Clubs':[10], 'Queen of Clubs':[10], 'Jack of Clubs':[10], 'Ace of Clubs': [1,11]
}